# What's the point of having __wakeup in source code of PHP 7.4 Exceptions?

Tags: php, c, exception, deserialization, magic-methods

There exists a (rather new) exploitation technique called [phar](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-n-t/presentations/master/us-18-Thomas-It's-A-PHP-Unserialization-Vulnerability-Jim-But-Not-As-We-Know-It.pdf) [deserialisation](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3853213/us-18-Thomas-It's-A-PHP-Unserialization-Vulnerability-Jim-But-Not-As-We-....pdf) which gets triggered by PHP's [file system functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) like `file_exists`, `unlink`, ... and then the unserialized code gets executed inside instantiated class which needs to contain at least one of two magic methods `__wakeup` and `__destruct`.

My idea was to search in PHP's source code for builtin PHP classes which might have such magic methods natively implemented (`__wakeup` and `__destruct`) as part of such classes and could be somehow exploited during deserialization process during *Exception* handling (which might trigger e.g. some use-after-free bugs). Indeed I found `__wakeup` in several *Exception* classes (Easy way of getting all builtin classes and check them for having `__wakeup` and `__destruct` methods is to use PHP function `get_declared_classes()`). But at current point it seems to be unexploitable.

So the question is not about exploiting things.

Question: What i don't understand is why e.g. `__wakeup` implemented in *Exceptions*? Is it just a placeholder method for extending such *Exception* classes and writing later own `__wakeup`/`__destruct` methods?

Source code:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_exceptions.c#L316

In lines 306-333 (*php-src/Zend/zend_exceptions.c*, PHP 7.4):

```
/* }}} */

/* {{{ proto Exception::__wakeup()
   Exception unserialize checks */
#define CHECK_EXC_TYPE(id, type) \
    pvalue = zend_read_property_ex(i_get_exception_base(object), (object), ZSTR_KNOWN(id), 1, &value); \
    if (Z_TYPE_P(pvalue) != IS_NULL && Z_TYPE_P(pvalue) != type) { \
        zend_unset_property(i_get_exception_base(object), object, ZSTR_VAL(ZSTR_KNOWN(id)), ZSTR_LEN(ZSTR_KNOWN(id))); \
    }

ZEND_METHOD(exception, __wakeup)
{
    zval value, *pvalue;
    zval *object = ZEND_THIS;
    CHECK_EXC_TYPE(ZEND_STR_MESSAGE,  IS_STRING);
    CHECK_EXC_TYPE(ZEND_STR_STRING,   IS_STRING);
    CHECK_EXC_TYPE(ZEND_STR_CODE,     IS_LONG);
    CHECK_EXC_TYPE(ZEND_STR_FILE,     IS_STRING);
    CHECK_EXC_TYPE(ZEND_STR_LINE,     IS_LONG);
    CHECK_EXC_TYPE(ZEND_STR_TRACE,    IS_ARRAY);
    pvalue = zend_read_property(i_get_exception_base(object), object, "previous", sizeof("previous")-1, 1, &value);
    if (pvalue && Z_TYPE_P(pvalue) != IS_NULL && (Z_TYPE_P(pvalue) != IS_OBJECT ||
            !instanceof_function(Z_OBJCE_P(pvalue), zend_ce_throwable) ||
            pvalue == object)) {
        zend_unset_property(i_get_exception_base(object), object, "previous", sizeof("previous")-1);
    }
}
/* }}} */
```

and later in lines 788-801:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_exceptions.c#L788

```
static const zend_function_entry default_exception_functions[] = {
    ZEND_ME(exception, __clone, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PRIVATE|ZEND_ACC_FINAL)
    ZEND_ME(exception, __construct, arginfo_exception___construct, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    ZEND_ME(exception, __wakeup, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    ZEND_ME(exception, getMessage, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_FINAL)
    ZEND_ME(exception, getCode, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_FINAL)
    ZEND_ME(exception, getFile, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_FINAL)
    ZEND_ME(exception, getLine, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_FINAL)
    ZEND_ME(exception, getTrace, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_FINAL)
    ZEND_ME(exception, getPrevious, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_FINAL)
    ZEND_ME(exception, getTraceAsString, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_FINAL)
    ZEND_ME(exception, __toString, NULL, 0)
    ZEND_FE_END
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, this code is verifying the types of the exception's properties and setting them to `null` if the type is incorrect. For example:

```
CHECK_EXC_TYPE(ZEND_STR_MESSAGE,  IS_STRING);
```

is roughly equivalent to the PHP code:

```
if (!is_string($this->message))
    $this->message = null;
```

Similarly, the code at the end, beginning with `pvalue = zend_read_property(…)`, is checking that `$this->previous` is an object which implements `Throwable`. In PHP, it'd be roughly equivalent to:

```
if (!is_object($this->previous) || !($this->previous instanceof Throwable)
    $this->previous = null;
```

As to why this code is part of the PHP interpreter? The entirety of the `Exception` class is defined there, in C code. None of the built-in classes or methods are written in PHP -- they cannot be, because the language provides no way to install a PHP implementation of a method to a class declared in C.

Comment: Well, you're describing the code of `CHECK_EXC_TYPE`. But I'm curious why `__wakeup` method of *Exception* class needs to be defined already at C level and not later at PHP level, where we can e.g. define such *magic methods* like `__destruct`. So I understand, that we are checking types in lines 306-333. But what is the point of defining `__wakeup` here? In lines 788-801: `ZEND_ME(exception, __wakeup, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)` is just saying that `__wakeup` is part of *Exception* class and is public. That's it. It's just so unclear what it is doing here.

Comment: Is the point of having `__wakeup` there is that it just enables deserialisation natively, (without defining own *Exception* classes) ? But since it doesn't have `__sleep` method it actually shouldn't be serialized (but it still works). So it just makes no sense to me.

Comment: "But I'm curious why `__wakeup` method of Exception class needs to be defined already at C level and not later at PHP level" -- Because there is no PHP code corresponding to the `Exception` class. The class is defined entirely within PHP, so any methods must be defibned there.

Comment: I think you're right. I think the point is that since *Exception* class should be deserializable it needs to have `__wakeup()` method added already at C level (since *Exception* class properties are defined in C too).

Comment: Maybe you can move your comment to your answer above, modify it a bit and I'll just mark it as answered. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that since Exception class should be deserializable it needs to have `__wakeup()` method added already at C level (since *Exception class* properties are defined in C too).